# Compare data frame and list to find highest priority value using R

Tags: r, dataframe

### Edited As per request

Team,

Need suggestion in below request.

I have a static list df2= c("Maths/Science", "Science/Engg", "Maths/Engg", "Maths","Science","Engg"). I need to compare each column of df1 with df2 and check if all these combinations are present or not. It can appear separately or in combination with other values as well.

Weightage is as follows

```
df2= c("Maths/Science", "Science/Engg", "Maths/Engg", "Maths","Science","Engg")

Maths/Science= 6
Science/Engg=5
Maths/Engg = 4
Maths=3
Science=2
Engg=1
```

A new dataframe df3 is created to include d1 data and new column as 'weightage' and mention the highest available values in the row(as per weightage).

Please find the data below,

df1-Input df1

```
dput(input)

structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths/Science", "Engg", "Commerce", 
"Engg"), Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", 
"Science/Engg"), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), 
    Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

d2

```
structure(list(Col_1 = "(\"Maths/Science\", \"Science/Engg\", \"Maths/Engg\", \"Maths\",\"Science\",\"Engg\")"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df3 output

```
structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths", "Engg", "Science", "Engg"), 
    Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "Engg", "Science/Engg"
    ), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), Col_4 = c("Maths/Science", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), Weightage = c("Maths/Science", "Science/Maths", 
    "Science/Engg", "Science/Engg")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Since you are adding weightage as a column, it seems to relate to the values on the same row, but you say you want to process by column so the first value in the  weightage column refers to the first column, not the first row? Also the first element in df1 is "Maths/Science", but the first value in df3 is "Maths". Is that a typo?

Comment: @Akshi Also, is `df2` missing?

Comment: Hi Dcarlson/Ben, added requested inputs

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear how you want to handle subjects, but this may be helpful for you.

First, create a vector and put in order your subjects based on weight:

```
vec <- c("Maths/Science", "Science/Engg", "Maths/Engg", "Maths", "Science", "Engg")
```

Then, you can convert your columns to factors, and use ordered levels based on your vector:

```
df_fac <- lapply(df1, factor, levels = vec, ordered = T)
```

Finally, you can get the minimum factor level (in this case highest weight, based on my ordered in the vector) for each row:

```
do.call(pmin, c(df_fac, na.rm = T))
```

You can assign to `df1$Weightage` and compare with your example.